# Why the stored procedure doesn't return the Arabic text matched values

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the Arabic matched values from a SQL Server 2008 database using a stored procedure. But it doesn't return the matched values.. why?

My table design is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #test1
(
col1 nVARCHAR(100)  ,
col2 nVARCHAR(100)  ,
col3 NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES(N'لا أتكلم العربية',N'لا أتكلم العربية',N'لا أتكلم العربية')
INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES( ' fdfdf', 'dfdfdf', '45dfdf')

SELECT * FROM #test1
```

it showing the result like below well...

```
col1    col2    col3
لا أتكلم العربية    لا أتكلم العربية    لا أتكلم العربية
 fdfdf  dfdfdf  45dfdf
```

The given query giving the exact results while I am searching for the Arabic words..

```
declare @ColVal nvarchar(100)

 set @ColVal=   N'لا أتكلم العربية'
print @ColVal
select * from #test1 where col2 like @ColVal
```

But when I am trying to retrieve the same data using a stored procedure, it doesn't show the matched rows anymore even they exist in table..

My stored procedure is

```
create proc Sp_TestArabic1 (@colValue nvarchar(100))
as
declare @ColVal nvarchar(100)
begin
set @ColVal=  'N'+@colValue
print @ColVal
select * from #test1 where col2 like @ColVal
end

exec Sp_TestArabic1 'لا أتكلم العربية'
```

Doesn't give any results, I tried with debugging the stored procedure, all the columns passes the values well but it doesn't returns the correct results..

Please provide exact solution to search the Arabic words based on the condition...

Thank you..

Comment: Also note: you should **not** use a `sp_` prefix for your stored procedure - that prefix has been reserved by Microsoft for future use. You should use some other prefix - anything is fine, just don't use `sp_` .

Answer (score 3):

You've got a couple of issues with the way you are specifying the unicode literal - do it on the constant passed into the proc, and don't prepend 'N' to your search otherwise it will look for `'Nلا أتكلم العربية'`

```
CREATE  proc Sp_TestArabic1 (@colValue nvarchar(100))
as
  begin
    select * from #test1 where col2 like @colValue
  end

exec Sp_TestArabic1 N'لا أتكلم العربية'
```

Out of interest using the arrow keys over the Arabic text in SQL 2008 intellisense is reversed - very weird :)

Comment: i used the stored procedure as you said.. but it results same...alter proc Sp_TestArabic (@colValue nvarchar(100))
as
begin
select * from #test1 where col2 like  @colValue
end

exec Sp_TestArabic  'لا أتكلم العربية'    returns no values...

Comment: exec Sp_TestArabic **N**'لا أتكلم العربية' - you still need to indicate that the string literal is Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
exec Sp_TestArabic N'لا أتكلم العربية'
```

Not

```
exec Sp_TestArabic 'لا أتكلم العربية'
```